# JSONObject["name"] not a string

Tags: java, json

I've been trying for the last couple hours to fix this. I'm a little rusty when it comes to Java and decided I wanted to finish this method where I'm trying to parse the json to get the name of a map.

```
private static void mapLookUp (String mapId){
    HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();


    try
    {
        URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("https://www.haloapi.com/metadata/h5/metadata/maps");

        URI uri = builder.build();
        HttpGetWithEntity request = new HttpGetWithEntity(uri);
        request.addHeader("ocp-apim-subscription-key", "aa09014c153b4a4b9c3a4937356e208a");

        // Request body
        StringEntity reqEntity = new StringEntity("{body}");
        request.setEntity(reqEntity);

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) 
        {
            String response2request = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            //System.out.println(response2request.length()+"\n"+response2request);

            String jsonString = "{\"Results\":"+response2request+"}";
            System.out.println(jsonString);

            JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            List<String> mapName = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> mapIds = new ArrayList<String>();
            JSONArray array = jsonResult.getJSONArray("Results");
            for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; i++){
                mapName.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
                mapIds.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));}
            for(int i = 0 ; i < mapIds.size() ; i++)
                if(mapIds.get(i).equals(mapId))
                    System.out.println("The most recent game was on "+mapName.get(i));
        }
        else
            System.out.println("NULL");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        System.out.println("Caught exception");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

In the output I get JSONObject["name"] not a string.

Comment: Instead of just getting the message, rewrite your catch block to print the entire stack trace.  The [edit] your question and add the full stacktrace to it.

Comment: what azurefrog pointed out means inside the catch (Exception e) you need to add call e.printStackTrace();

Comment: Can you please also provide value you are passing while making the call to mapLookUp, that is the mapId. And at what step are you getting the output, I do not see you returning any value as the response type for the method mapLookUp is void.

Comment: From where are you getting HttpGetWithEntity. Please also post API jars you are using

Answer (score 1):

check JSON source. It seems like it may have no " around name value, or name is an object.
as example something like:

```
...
"name":John Doe,
...
or
"name":{"first":"John", "last":"Doe"},
...
```

BTW: Second is more expected. First must fail before, because it is wrong JSON. Value with no " around must be a number. But maybe name is empty like:

```
...
"name":,
...
```